# Vue lazy loading webpackChunkName does not group in chunks but generates a bunch of individual files with a number

Tags: vue.js, webpack, lazy-loading, vue-router

I'm trying to implement lazy loading in vue router but when I add the magic comment for webpack it does changes the name of the chunk but it does not group them when they have the same name (see picture 1). Is this normal or am I doing something wrong?

Picture 1:
[screenshot of prefetched files in network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3J8i.png)

Code:

````
```
function lazyAuthenticationComponents(component) {

return () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Authentication" */`@/components/Authentication/${component}.vue`)
}

export default {
  path: '/auth', redirect: '/auth/login',
  component: lazyAuthenticationComponents('Authentication'),
  children: [
    {
      path: 'login',
      component: ()=> import(/* webpackChunkName: "Authentication" */ '@/pages/Authentication/Login/LoginView.vue'),
      name: 'login'
    },

```
````

All other routes use the  lazyAuthenticationComponents function because they share a common path, the only one that is located somewhere else has its own individual import, as I said before I do get the prefetched files but not in just one chunk but multiple.

Im using "vue": "^2.6.12",

Comment: I think that when you use dynamic imports with JavaScript template literal Webpack imports **all** files in the given folder because it does not know what value will receive the argument `component` at run-time. Try computing the filepath separately and providing a string constant to the `import()` statement.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t comment before, I finally decided to do every import separately as you suggested, and it's working.